# AFHTTPSessionManager attemptsToRecreateUploadTasksForBackgroundSessions property equivalent in Alamofire 5

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, afnetworking

Previously I used AFNetworking and set `attemptsToRecreateUploadTasksForBackgroundSessions` to YES for some custom sessions. I'm trying to migrate to Alamofire 5 and I can't find any equivalent of this property. Should I handle it somehow or Alamofire already does it under the hood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent. Alamofire does not currently support background `URLSession`s.